# Treeview & Radiobutton

Tags: delphi-7

Привет Всем. 
Мне тут помощь нужна, по делфи,беру я компонент treeview и можно ли в него вставить какой нибудь компонент, в котором будет список в котором нужно выбрать один пункт вспомощью компонента radiobutton. то есть там перед каждым вариантом стоит radio button и один из них надо выбрать?

Answer (score 2):

Стандартный TreeView такие вещи делать не умеет. Посмотрите в сторону [Virtual TreeView](http://code.google.com/p/virtual-treeview/).

[image]